# Does anyone know what this wildflower is?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

These flowers grow wild on the hill at my grandparents' place in Zone 6 in Missouri. The bees certainly did love them last summer. Does anyone know what they are?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [*Lunaria annua*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunaria_annua) (Honesty, Money Plant, etc.).