# What is this decorative flower (or membrane) (or seed) (or leaf) (or fruit)?

Tags: identification, flowers

Do you know the latin name of this plant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Update: There appear to be two more questions about the same species on this site:

[Does anyone know what this wildflower is?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/does-anyone-know-what-this-wildflower-is)

[What are these small brown curved seeds?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/what-are-these-small-brown-curved-seeds)

A picture from the first question above: (one can notice oval membranes (in the top right potion of the photo) that are green at that stage, and contain seeds in the middle that just started developing - just incredible)

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is Lunaria annua.  Some call it the money or silver dollar plant. [Lunaria annua](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/01/e0/fe/01e0fe926c0bf1db8136741f0a6234bd.jpg)  You are looking at the seed of this plant.

Comment: Actually what we're seeing in this picture is the center membrane.  Seeds are house on either side, and are covered with another membrane. [image of seed](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/35/8e/a9358e8232d2e25d340d7711d50bf112.jpg)  If I think about I'll try and take some more details shots when I'm at work.

Comment: So it is the fruit, Translucent, so one can see the seeds (not so different from elm, but different family)

Comment: This is from South East Europe, but it can be invasive in temperate places.

Comment: We find them in North-West Europe as well (Netherlands). We call them in Dutch "Judas penning", which is translated to English 'Judas penny' or 'Judas coin'. Funny name.

Comment: ANother name in the UK is [*honesty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunaria_annua)

Comment: @Ben, wait, is then this specimen on my photos then some seedless variety? Or did the seeds already fell off?

Comment: Seeds already feel off.  The outer membrane is sort of dirty gray and you can see the black sees through it.  As it dries, that outer membrane peals off and the seeds fall off.  The inner membrane is what is left and is what you have.

Comment: @Ben Unreal. :-o

Comment: Here are a couple of pictures of the seed pods with seeds: [one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Lunaria_annua_seeds_J1.JPG) [two](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Lunaria_annua_seeds_J3.JPG)

Comment: Plants are just cool.  I said 'looking at the seed' versus the leaves or membrane for clarification.  The seed making mechanism?  Grins.  If you want to keep the membranes for dried flower arrangements spray them with hair spray.  Try to get unscented, cheapo, aerosoled hair spray.  Works well for all dried flowers.  Great way to 'freshen' and clean the dried fragile flowers.  Holds them together and doesn't make a sticky mess.  I thought it would but, just TMI I know!! Grins.

Comment: [photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/39xfOUlyorFe7tiy1) it was wonderful to catch them with the light shining through them.  Just used theses shots on my Instagram feed.